# Copy text file content into text area

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to copy and paste the huge content in a text file into text area of my application.

```
//Read content from text file
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        String xml_file = "";
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            xml_file += line;
        }

//Driver code
element.sendKeys(xml_file)
```

This code actually works but the problem is its taking around 10 mins to write the content into text area.

Is there any other possible ways to do this?

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: Try using StringBuilder instead of concatenating strings, String concatenation is pretty slow.

Comment: @aBnormaLz, file size is 26 KB and it has 600 lines

Comment: Try removing `xml_file += line;` and place 
`element.sendKeys(line);` inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

I used JS which took fraction of seconds to write the data into textarea

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+ xml_file+"';", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#id")));
```